# How to remove special characters from input fields while pasting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, input, special-characters

I'm trying to implement functionality where if a user pastes text it should remove `<`, `>`, `$` and `!`.

The following code works on all inputs. Currently it disables the paste function.

```js
function specialCharRestriction() {
  setTimeout(function(e) {
    $('input, textarea').bind("cut copy paste", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    
    $('input:not([type=password]), textarea').on('keypress', function(e) {
      var blockSpecialRegex = /[!$(){}[\]:;<+?\\>]/;
      var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
      
      if (blockSpecialRegex.test(key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
  }, 500);
}
```

Instead, I want something like this:

```
$('input').val().replace(regex, '');
```

This way it can be applied on all inputs and I don't have to select all the inputs one by one. There are more than 100 fields declared in my project so please help with some generic code which can be applied on all input fields.

Edit: I want that whenever someone pastes `<Naruto>` then only `Naruto` should be pasted and <> should be omitted.  following code only works once, and then special characters are being pasted.

Comment: The event handlers will already be bound to any `input` or `textarea` element, so I'm not sure what the latter half of your question is asking...?

Comment: I want that whenever someone pastes <Naruto> then only Naruto should be pasted and <> should be omitted.
`<input type="text" id="myInput">` following code only works once, and then special characters are being pasted.

Comment: If you use `g` (global) option in your regex, maybe you have your work done by replacing the current text: `$('input').val($('input').val().replace(/[!$(){}[\]:;<+?\\>]/g, ''))`.

Comment: Sorry, but your question makes no sense... let me play it back to you:   *"This code works on all inputs... instead I want something that can be applied to all inputs*".    Err...

Comment: If your inputs are generated *after* your code runs, then the existing event handlers won't be applied [to the new elements].  Instead you need event delegation:  `$(document).on("keypress", "input:not([type=password]), textarea", function() ...`

Comment: Actually I wrote something and I got suggestion to improve it. The question is The current code works on all inputs and disable paste function. However I want a code which replaces special characters on paste. Apologies for that. I see Manual Romeiro has helped with a code I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input, textarea').bind("input", function(e) {
  var blockSpecialRegex = /[!$(){}[\]:;<+?\\>]/g;
  let txtOrig = $(this).val();
  let txtFinal = txtOrig.replace(blockSpecialRegex, '');
  if (txtOrig !== txtFinal) {
    // Some blocked special chars was found and removed
    // Warning: this will move the cursor to the end!
    $(this).val(txtFinal);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
input1:<input id="txt1"><br>
input2:<input id="txt2"><br>
input3:<input id="txt3"><br>
textarea1:<textarea id="txt4"></textarea><br>
textarea2:<textarea id="txt5"></textarea><br>
textarea3:<textarea id="txt6"></textarea><br>
```

Comment: The following code given by Mr. Manuek Romeiro is working awesome. Thanks a bunch.